# Draw a map of a specific country with leaflet

Tags: r, maps, leaflet, geospatial, r-leaflet

I would like to use the package `leaflet` with R to draw a map of a specific countries such as Italy, Spain, etc.

I checked the basic examples with the function `setView()` and I tried to give a vector of two values for the arg of latitude and longitutde :

```
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  setView(lng=c(46.00,48.00), lat=c(2.00,6.00), zoom = 4)
m  # Print the map (map is not centered on a country, it's just a test)
```

But I will never be able to have a specific country on my screen such as the result of this function :

```
library(maps)
map('italy', fill = TRUE, col = 1:10)
```

In the end, I just want to draw some points by geographically locating them on my maps (with latitude and longtitude)

Is it possible or is the package `maps` is adequate for this task (even though I didn't find a way to zoom in) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `maps` package ships shapefile data as vertices. Afaik nothing like this is included in leaflet. So you will have to get your data elsewhere. Here is my suggestion:

```
# Get an Italy shapefile
download.file(url = 'http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/ITA_adm.zip', 
              destfile = 'italy.zip')
unzip(zipfile = 'italy.zip')

# Load libraries
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
italy <- readOGR('ITA_adm0.shp')

library(leaflet)
leaflet(italy) %>%
  addPolygons() %>%
  addTiles()
```

[image]

**ADD-ON:**

You can look at the vertices that make up italy as saved in the `maps` package with the code below.

```
library(maps)
italy <- map('italy', fill = TRUE, col = 1:10)
italy_coords <- cbind(italy$x, italy$y)
plot(italy_coords)
```

[image]

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful!

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the polygons retreived from `maps`. Of course one can use any other suitable source, just like [@JanLauGe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457259/janlauge) mentioned it.

After you have the polygons of the specific country you can feed them to Leafet after converting them to `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. You can also create a mask, if you want to display just the area of interest.

Naturally, after that you can easily add any point or marker with the standard Leaflet methods, like `addCircleMarkers( lng, lat )`.

```
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

country   <- 'italy';
zoomLevel <- 6;

# Get the map ( class is map )
ita.map <- map( country, fill = TRUE, col = 1, plot = F );

# Get the geo center for lazyness
ita.center <- geocode( "italy" );

# Extract the names from ita.map.
# e.g. "Trapani:I. Le Egadi:I. Marettimo" -> "Trapani"
# note: any other solution is fine, because we don't really need them, but they
# can be useful later
ita.map.ids <- sapply( strsplit( ita.map$names, ':' ), function(x) x[1] );
# Convert our map object to SpatialPolygons
ita.sp <- map2SpatialPolygons( ita.map, IDs=ita.map.ids,
    proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Note: if you only need a unified polygon, it can be achieved by fortify
# ita.sp.df <- fortify( ita.sp );

# Finally convert our SpatialPolygons to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
tmp.id.df <- data.frame( ID = names(ita.sp) );
rownames( tmp.id.df ) <- names( ita.sp );
ita.spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( ita.sp, tmp.id.df );

# Visualize
l.ita.map <- leaflet( ita.spdf ) %>% 
    setView(lng = ita.center$lon, lat = ita.center$lat, zoom = zoomLevel ) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addPolygons( data = ita.spdf, weight = 1, fillColor = "blue", fillOpacity = 0.5 );

l.ita.map
```

[image: Map of Italy from from ploygons]

```
####### Alternatively if a mask if needed #######

# Get a plane of the world
wld.sp <- rasterToPolygons( raster(ncol = 1, nrow = 1, crs = proj4string(ita.sp) ) );
# Cut our country polygon from the plane to get our target mask
ita.sp.mask <- gDifference( wld.sp, ita.sp );

# Convert our ita.sp.mask (SpatialPolygons) to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
tmp.id.df <- data.frame( ID = "1" );
rownames( tmp.id.df ) <- names( ita.sp.mask );
ita.mask.spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( ita.sp.mask, tmp.id.df );

# Coordinates of Rome
ita.rome.center <- geocode( "Rome, italy" );

# Visualize
l.ita.mask.map <- leaflet( ita.mask.spdf ) %>% 
    setView( lng = ita.center$lon, lat = ita.center$lat, zoom = zoomLevel ) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addPolygons( data = ita.mask.spdf, fillColor = "white", fillOpacity = 1.0, color = "black", weight = 1 ) %>%
addCircleMarkers(lng = ita.rome.center$lon, lat = ita.rome.center$lat );

l.ita.mask.map;
```

[image: Masked map of Italy from from ploygons]

Thanks for [@fdetsch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/13504/fdetsch/) for his [suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231103/cutting-leaflet-map-in-r-to-a-specific-area)!

Comment: Great extension of my answer, thanks!
Did not know about the `map2SpatialPolygons` function.