# Draw a map of a specific country with leaflet in django

Tags: python, django, leaflet

I am new to concept of maps and would like to create a leaflet map that only displays one country and possibility to add polylines or waypoints on top of that.
This has been done in R, but I can't quite grasp on how to do that in python yet.
[Draw a map of a specific country with leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093712/draw-a-map-of-a-specific-country-with-leaflet)

I have geoJSON file of the contry border.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing this i fixed it using plugin [snogylop](https://github.com/ebrelsford/Leaflet.snogylop)

And initialized map with style:

```
$.getJSON(dataurl, function (data) {
    // Add GeoJSON layer
    var style = {
        "color": "#red",
        "fillColor": 'white',
        "weight": 5,
        "fillOpacity": 1
    };

    L.geoJSON(data, {invert: true, style: style}).addTo(map);
});
```

This plugin basically inverts mask, and I then put this mask color to white